# Nontrivial polynomial relation for real $n \times n$ matrices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am going through Michael Artin's *Algebra* book to brush up on concepts and question M.2 at the end of chapter 3, Vector Spaces, struck me as odd:

> Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix. Prove that there is an integer $N$ such that $A$ satisfies a nontrivial polynomial relation $A^N+c_{N-1}A^{N-1}+\cdots+c_1A+c_0=0$.

My question is this: what does it mean by $c_1A+c_0$? $c_1A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, whereas $c_0$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix so they cannot be added, right? Also, I am assuming by $0$, Artin means the zero matrix.

Comment: Being pedantically formal, it should be $\;c_0I\;$ , and of course: the zero matrix.

Comment: $c_1 A$ means only that you are multiplying every element of your matrix $A$ by $c_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints.**

1. The real matrices form a real vector space of finite dimension.
2. Consider the powers of $A$.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: @lhf Yes, but answers the next question: how to prove it once you understand the notation.

Answer (score 1):

cA<sup>M</sup> means the number: c multiplied by the matrix: A<sup>M</sup>. Here an example: c = 2 and A =

0 1 
-1 0

Then cA<sup>2</sup> =

-2  0 
 0 -2

Now the expression $\Sigma_{J=1}^N c_{J}A^{J}$ has $n^2$ components. So $\Sigma_{J=1}^N c_{J}A^{J} = 0$ is a set of N equations in the $N \equiv n^2$ unknowns $\{c_J\}$ and must be solvable in principle. More to the point, if $\{\lambda_K\}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $c_J$ is the coefficent of $x^J$ in the expansion of $\Pi (x - \lambda_K)$ then $\Sigma_{J=1}^N c_{J}A^{J} = 0$

Answer (score 1):

$c_1A + c_0$ simply means $c_1$ times the matrix $A$ plus $c_0$ times the identity matrix. Likewise, the $0$ on the right hand side of your equation is indeed the zero matrix.